# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} ((15)^n +([(1+0.0001)^{10000}])^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, soft-question, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} ((15)^n +([(1+0.0001)^{10000}])^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$  Here [.] denotes the greatest integer function.

My Try : I know how to solve this kind of problem :$\lim_{n \to \infty} ((a)^n +(b)^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$  where $a, b \geq 0$. But here I can not find $([(1+0.0001)^{10000}])$?

Can anyone please help me out?

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$$2\le\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \le e < 3$$

we have that

$$\left((15)^n +\left[\left(1+\frac1{10000}\right)^{10000}\right]^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}= \left((15)^n +2^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=15 \left(1 +(2/15)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 15$$

Comment: Don't you have to mention that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is an increasing sequence?@gimusi

Comment: @cmi no it suffices to know that it’s bounded in between 2 and 3

Comment: Yea...I can think that way...@gimusi

Answer (score 7):

Hint: since
$$
\lim_n \left(1 + \frac 1n\right)^n = \mathrm e \in [2,3],
$$
so the integral part of your expression should be…?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \le e < 3$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a = 15, b = [(1+10^{-4})^{10000}]=3$. We have that a > b. So:
$$
\begin{align}
(a^n+b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} &= \exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\ln(a^n+b^n)\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(\ln(a^n)+\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n\right)\right)\right) \\
&= a\cdot\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n\right)\right) \\
& \underset{n\infty}{\longrightarrow}a
\end{align}
$$.

Comment: @gimusi The question uses the floor function. So, while your answer is correct, you can skip the steps with the squeeze theorem :)

Comment: @Jam ops sorry I lost that part, I fix. Thanks a lot

Comment: Wrong integer part.